# Recover data from firebase, problem Firebase.class

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to recover a data to base fire.. But the application close at demmarage.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mValueView;
    private Firebase mRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        mValueView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        mRef = new Firebase("https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com/");

        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                mValueView.setText(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

In my Firebase.class at the top there is a word: [Decompiled .class file, bytecode versio: 50.0 (java 6) [Donwload source OR Choose source).

I try to donwload source 
and display Studio cannot determine what kind of files the chosen items contain. Do you want to attach them as 'Sources'?]. 
I take (yes) and nothing happens.

I am using the implementation 'com.firebase: firebase-client-android: 2.3.1'

Thank you.

Comment: you are using a very old version of firebase

Comment: which one to use?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android this, also check the website to see how to use it

Comment: already done: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'

Answer (score 1):

You are using a very old version, check the following link to see how to update:

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

Example, change the following:

```
 mRef = new Firebase("https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com/");
```

into this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Also you need to use the following in the root build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    }
}
```

and in the app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

The version you are using is very old, it is before google acquired firebase. Now the Firebase SDK is in the google repository (`google()`).

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html